# Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) crashes on Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise)

Tags: installation, java, eclipse, jdk, auto-completion

I installed eclipse 4.2 java on Ubuntu 12.04 x86_64 and it just crashes everytime it opens the auto completion context menu. It crashes without any error message and just closes the eclipse window. Interestingly, it also crashes when I click on of the menu points in Edit->Content Assist AND it crashes when I click in the Window->Preferences on the menu point General->Web Browser. (I experienced that because I wanted to switch off auto completion, but I couldn't find it.)

Does anybody have a clue what's wrong? I can provide any information you need, just let me know. I can also perform steps that might seem promising to you and report the results.

Some information that might be interesting to you:

I have tried with different versions of java JDK, e.g. openjdk-6-jdk, openjdk-7-jdk, oracle-6-jdk, oracle-7-jdk, and different versions of eclipse, e.g. eclipse 3.7 (Indigo) and eclipse 4.2 (Juno). Nothing worked out, but maybe I did it wrong because I had to install oracle-jdk's manually.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_15"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.7) (7u15-2.3.7-0ubuntu1~12.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

$ javac -version
javac 1.7.0_15
```

Comment: On the web browser part it probably doesn't have the firefox mini-browser/library whatever it embeds (I've seen that before).  The other ones, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

There could be a bug that has been fixed. 
You can try and run an update on Eclipse: 
Click on the menu Help, then on Check for updates.

You will then wait a bit and if there are updates, a list of packages will come up. Just follow the instructions on the screen.